# PHP unlink from a list of files posted via HTML

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to build an HTML form that accepts a file list, and sends it over to the php script to delete it. I've got a very barebones thing going on here with HTML form to accept the file names:

```
<form method="post" action="unlink.php">
File list<br />
<textarea cols="40" rows="10" name="files"></textarea><br />
<input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

and the php to retrieve these files and delete it:

```
<?php

$files = $_POST['files'];

$delete = unlink($files);

if ($delete)
{
    echo "Successfully deleted files";
}
```

This works great for single files, however, I'm looking to delete multiple files. If for example I pass 1.txt and 2.txt as the file names, it tries to delete: unlink(1.txt 2.txt).  I am probably doing this wrongly, but does anyone have any suggestions on how I can get this working? Thanks.

Comment: Use an `array()` and use the `unlink()` in a loop `foreach`

Comment: how do you enter filenames in the textarea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Textarea value (for one file on each line):

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.doc
file.pdf
```

PHP:
Split file name, loop them and do what's needed

```
if(isset($_POST['files'])){
    $files = $_POST['files'];
    $list = explode("\r\n", $files);

    foreach($list as $file){
        if(@unlink($file)){
           echo "$file deleted<br />";
        }
        else{
           echo "$file not deleted<br />";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `foreach` loop on an array of items you need to unlink.

```
foreach($array as $item){
 unlink($item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php to split your string into chunks (in your case file names; you have to define a delimter such as space or a newline character; this should also be known by the user entering multiple file names!). Afterwards you could use foreach to iterate through the array returned by the previous explode command; https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php.

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting the file names and using a while loop to run through them all

```
$files = $_POST['files'];
$allfiles = explode(" ", $files); //Separates the file names by spaces

$i = 0;
while ($allfiles[$i] != null) { //A loop to delete all of the files
  $delete = unlink($allfiles[$i]);
  if ($delete)
  {
      echo "Successfully deleted file";
  }
  $i++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks everyone. I tried your example now Spencer, however, it seems to skip the file extensions now. I tried submitting 1.txt and 2.txt as file names, but got the error:

Warning: unlink(1): No such file or directory

Any clue as to why that is?

Comment: It breaks the text up by spaces. So you would have to put it in like this 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt etc.. no "and"

Comment: Ah yes, I should have looked at that more closely. Thank you too! :)